# Why can't I delete broken Python packages? - "WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ycopg2"

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have been trying to install psycopg2 correctly for a while now- after installing it when I try to push my app on Heroku, I get the `'wheel is broken'` error.

Now when I do `pip list`, I get the following Warning messages:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -sycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -sycopg2 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
```

Furthermore, when I try to pip/sudo pip uninstall `-ycopg2` ; I get:

```
Usage:   
  /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -c
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice, I did come across this solution, but the top suggestions do not work- I run into exactly the same output as my problem above. However, I didn't try to delete the packages from "site-packages" as suggested lower down in the thread. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Never mind- I figured it out. Thanks